# Restrict one computer to only talk to one FTP

Tags: networking, windows-7, ubuntu-12.04

I have a rip station for a few digital printers that I want to limit access, internet, usage, and anything that could cause an issue and only allow that rip station to get access/files from my FTP.  My rip station is Windows 7 64 and my FTP is Ubuntu 12.04.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your FTP station has a static IP address or is on the same local network, you could simply set your firewall rules on the rip station to only allow outgoing and incoming port 21 (assuming you are using a non encrypted FTP connection) to the IP address of the FTP server.

This will probably be insufficient if you are trying to connect through the internet to a computer with a dynamic IP address, as used by most broadband connections.

If it is on the local network it may help to assign the FTP station an IP address manually rather than by DHCP, to eliminate the chance of it changing when more computers are added to the network.

Comment: everything is in a LAN. My apologies I am in no way knowledgeable in networking other than being able to configure a router and running/splicing Cat5e

Comment: that should be fine, your router probably has a local IP address such as 192.168.1.1, and then assigns each computer on the LAN 192.168.1.x. You just need to assign a particular address statically for the FTP server in the router setup, and then set the firewall rules to match on the rip station.

Comment: would it be good to learn how to assign IPs and go that route?  I dont mind learning but I dont know where to go to get quality guidance.

Comment: Yes, the hardest part is probably finding the correct page of settings in the router setup. I would search online for the make and model of your router to find the manual if you have doubts. You will probably need to tell the FTP server what its static address is once you make the change.